# Read string in ascii and insert on database

Tags: c#, sql, unicode, utf-8, ascii

i need to convert this string, the string most by convert is with '@' on the begining the variable can't change

@"\5B)>\1E06\1DY" + variable1 + @"\1D" + variable2 + @"\1D12V" + variable3 + @"\1DT11" + variable4 + "00" + variable5 + @"\1E\04"

this is a 2D barcode

to be the same string that my barcode read, to insert on sql and verify if it's the same string.

´)>06Y1310101000000XP2459126212V901334578T1122036000046665(need to by like this)

Comment: you need to elaborate more as this does not provide information on a problem you're having

Comment: I'm confused... if you use a verbatim string literal like `@"\5B)..."` then the string *literally contains* `'\'`. `'5'` and `'B'` - but your string at the end does not have those tokens... so: what are you trying to do here? what output are you after? and what values of `variable1` etc do you have? basically: what do we need to do to see what you're seeing, and what problem are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple like this :

```
            string input = "06Y1310101000000XP2459126212V901334578T1122036000046665";
            string variable1 = input.Substring(3, 22);
            string variable2 = input.Substring(29, 9);
            string variable3 = input.Substring(41, 5);
            string variable4 = input.Substring(48, 2);
            string variable5 = input.Substring(50, 1);
```